# how to make 2d shape deformations?

Tags: interpolation

I'm trying to make an animation transition between 2 shapes, example: transform a square into a circle... or transform a triangle into 2 squares

pretty much like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSxul.jpg
(no rep for posting images)

my first idea is to interpolate 2 planes and give them 2 different values of Z, and then interpolate the shape of one plane into the other... but how?

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize both curves by normalized arc length. Now use the homotopy $H(s,t)=(1-t)A(s)+tB(s)$.

Comment: That doesn't immediately apply for "triangle into 2 squares", however. (But one might imagine tricks like arbitrarily connecting the two squares with an invisible umbilical).